# Viewstate inheritance

Tags: asp.net, telerik, viewstate

I have an ASP.NET application that has a bunch of Telerik controls on the default.aspx page. As I have come to learn, Telerik controls will crash the viewstate frequently, so they either need to be removed entirely from the page or removed from the viewstate (<-- preferably this).

The issue is, I load all of the .ascx files into an asp panel that is nested within Telerik controls (splitter, panel, etc). If the viewstate is disabled for the Telerik controls that surround the asp panel which loads the .ascx files, it seems to be inherited by those pages.

Is there a way to stop this inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

The `ViewStateMode` property can be set for the child control whose viewstate you want to keep: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstatemode(v=vs.110).aspx

If you keep getting viewstate errors frequently, however, it is likely that something in the setup (like programmatic control creation) is wrong, because Telerik controls do not cause that issue themselves.